# How to get all the appender names in logback

Tags: java, logging, logback, logback-classic

How to get a list of all the appender names which have been set in a List in Java while using logback.

Answer (score 10):

The following code will gather all appenders in the current `LoggerContext`:

```
private Map<String, Appender<ILoggingEvent>> getAppendersMap() {
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();


    Map<String, Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appendersMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Logger logger : loggerContext.getLoggerList()) {

        Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appenderIterator = logger.iteratorForAppenders();
        while (appenderIterator.hasNext()) {
            Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = appenderIterator.next();
            if (!appendersMap.containsKey(appender.getName())) {
                appendersMap.put(appender.getName(), appender);
            }
        }
    }

    return appendersMap;
}
```

You can then list the names like so:

```
Map<String, Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appendersMap = getAppendersMap();

for (String key : appendersMap.keySet()) {
    logger.info("appender name = {}", key);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Thanks @glytching.

I found a shorter answer:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
for (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {
    for (Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> index = logger.iteratorForAppenders(); index.hasNext();) {
        Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = index.next();
    }
}
```